# Firebase functions with AdminSdk and RealtimeDatabase not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to create, edit, read and delete on the RealTime Database using the firebase functions. Looking at other similar questions I saw that the AdminSdk has to be used, and so I did. 
I basically copy/pasted the code provided by the same firebase guides.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});

const db = admin.database();

db.ref("devices")
.once("value")
.then(snapshot => console.log("Snapshot: ",snapshot.val())
.catch(error => console.log(error))
});
```

In the initialization I set the credential with applicationDefault() as I previously set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable with my service_account_key.json path.
I tried anyway to set it with the cert method and the result didn't change. As 3 accounts are showed in the Service account section I tried with all of them as well.

This said,when starting the functions from console with 'firebase serve' the log is not showed and no error either.

Is there anything I'm missing? Some further configuration or whatever error you might be aware of?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update following your comments:**

You want to "create, edit, read and delete on the Realtime Database using Cloud Functions", as indicated in your question, **mimicking the behaviour of a Client SDK** but from a server that you control. You should use one or more Cloud Functions that you call directly from this server. The most appropriate (based on your comments) would be to use an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

For example you could have an HTTPS Cloud Function like the simple one below, to write to a specific node of the Realtime Database, as follows:

```
exports.writeToNode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const dbNode = req.body.nodeRef;
        const objToWrite = req.body.nodeValue;

        return admin.database().ref(dbNode).push(objToWrite)
            .then(() => {
                return res.send("Node " + dbNode + " updated!");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //please watch the official video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3 
            });

    });
});
```

You would call it by issuing a POST to the following URL `https://us-central1-YOURPROJECTID.cloudfunctions.net/writeToNode`, with a body like:

```
   {
        nodeRef: 'theNode',
        nodeValue: {
          firstName: 'John',
          lastName: 'Doe'
        }
      }
```

---

**Initializing the Admin SDK:**

If you want to interact, from a Cloud Function, with the Realtime Database that is in the same Firebase project, you just need to initialize the Admin SDK without any parameter (i.e. `admin.initializeApp();`)

This way, the Admin SDK will use the Project's default service account, and will have full access to the Realtime Database (i.e. bypassing all the security rules).

So, initialize as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
```

---

**///// Additional thought /////**

Note that you could maybe use the REST API exposed by the Realtime Database, instead of developing an entire set of CRUD endpoints through Cloud Functions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

---

**REMAINING PART OF THE CONTENT OF THE INITIAL ANSWER, about background triggered Cloud Functions**

You then need to declare a Cloud Function, as shown in the example below, by:

1. Selecting an "[event handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler)";
2. Specifying the database path where it will listen for events and;
3. Executing the desired logic (normally using the data that was written at the path, or indicating that the node was deleted, etc...)

---

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/devices/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```

This code snippet, copied from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), will listen to any new node created under the `devices` node and will create an `uppercase` node the value of the `original` node in uppercase.

Note that this is a background triggered Cloud Function which is triggered when something "happens" at the specific path.

If you want to "create, edit, read and delete on the RealTime Database", as indicated in your question, **mimicking the behaviour of a Client SDK**, you may define one or more Cloud Functions that you call directly from your App. See the Callable Cloud Functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

---

You may alse read the following documentation items https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events and also watch the video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

Comment: I want to make CRUD operations, not listen for CRUD events and then make the operations. I need to remove the onEventName and be able to directly access the db

Comment: Ok, see the bottom of my answer: "If you want to 'create, edit, read and delete on the RealTime Database', as indicated in your question, mimicking the behaviour of a Client SDK"... use a set of Callable Cloud Functions.

Comment: but this way I need to pass the data to my client to actually update the database and I would need my client to trigger the callable function somehow. In my specific case I have an external client (not using my firebase app) making a post request  to a route of an Express server created in the functions. When this route receives data it should write on the database.

Comment: Ok, it is more clear. Then you can use an HTTP Cloud Function, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps. I will write a (very) simple example of Cloud Fucntion in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I actually already put up the express server with different routes. Just didn't post them as I was trying to solve this issue first

Comment: @Blank Thinking again about your requirements, it appears that you could maybe use the REST API exposed by the Realtime Database, instead of developing an entire set of CRUD endpoints through Cloud Functions! See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: @Reanaud Tarnec In your functions.https.onRequest you use the admin.database(). Ad said above my AdminSdk is not working, therefore when I call the push or once method nothing happens. This is the main issue I'm trying to solve. The REST API is definitely an option but I'd like to avoid them as further config might be necessary in the fetch requests

Comment: Look at the section "Initializing the Admin SDK" in my answer.

Comment: Look at the code I posted above. Even removing the configuration object didn't work.

Comment: The issue is somewhere else. Did you actually run the code you posted and saw the AdminSdk working correctly?

Comment: See the update and also https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app

Comment: Yes I did run the code, with success. And I do confirm that Cloud Functions work with such an initialization. You may start a brand new project if you still encounter problems.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!!! I was missing the async call. In the guide from firebase no async call is made and that didn't actually popped up in my mind